# Solving ODE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

This is actually a PDE problem, but after I use the method of separation of variables, I get this ODE.

Given $y''(x)+(4+\lambda)y(x)=0$ and $y(0)=1, y(\pi)=-1$.

So, this is my attempt to solve this ODE.

We consider three cases for $\lambda$.

**Case 1**: if $\lambda = -4$.

So ODE becomes $y''(x)=0$. The general solution is $y(x)=Ax+B$. From $y(0)=1, y(\pi)=-1$, we get $y(x) = -\frac{2}{\pi}x + 1$.

**Case 2**: if $\lambda < -4$.

Let $4+\lambda =-\alpha^2$, for some $\alpha>0$.

ODE becomes $y''(x)-\alpha^2 y(x)=0$. The general solution is $y(x)=Ae^{\alpha x}+Be^{-\alpha x}$.

From $y(0)=1$, we get $1=A+B \rightarrow B=1-A$.

From $y(\pi)=-1$, we get $-1 = A(e^{\alpha x} -e^{-\alpha x})+e^{-\alpha x}$

**So, how can we find the solution for this case?** I'm stuck here because there are two variables, $A$ and $\alpha$.

**Case 3**: if $\lambda > 4$.

Let $4+\lambda =\alpha^2$, for some $\alpha>0$.

ODE becomes $y''(x)+\alpha^2 y(x)=0$. The general solution is $y(x)=A \cos(\lambda x)+B \sin(\lambda x)$

From $y(0)=1$, we get $A=1$

From $y(\pi)=-1$, we get $-1=\cos(\alpha \pi)+B\sin(\alpha \pi)$

**So, how can we find the solution for this case?** I'm stuck here because there are two variables, $B$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: You should make the boundary conditions homogeneous before you apply separation of variables.

Comment: The boundary conditions is $u(0,t)=1$ and $u(\pi, t)=-1$. How to make the boundary conditions homogeneous?

Comment: By making the transformation $u(x,t) = v(x,t) + \tilde{v}(x)$ where $v(0,t) = v(\pi, t) = 0$ and $\tilde{v}$ is a function you need to construct such that $u(0,t) = 1 = v(0,t) + \tilde{v}(0) \implies \tilde{v}(0) = 1$ and analagously $\tilde{v}(\pi) = -1$. A solution that works is $$\tilde{v}(x) = - \frac{2x}{\pi} + 1$$ which you probably recognise. Your PDE might now have an inhomogeneous term attached, but your boundary conditions are homogeneous and so your solution $v$ is amenable to separation of variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint!

Comment: By the way, my PDE is $u_t=u_{xx}+4u, 0<x<\pi, t>0$. I think, we can't use $\tilde{v}(x)$ as you said before

Comment: Why can't we use $\tilde{v}(x)$?

Comment: $\tilde{v}(x)$ is a steady state solution, isn't it? And steady state solution happens if $u_t=0$. So, if $u_t=0$, it means $u_{xx}+4u=0$. And if we solve this equation, the solution (steady state solution) is $\tilde{v}(x)=c_1 \cos(2x) + c_2 \sin(2x)$. If we apply $\tilde{v}(0)=1$ and $\tilde{v}(\pi)=-1$, I think we get contradiction. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: $\tilde{v}$ is just a function that is used to make the boundary conditions homogeneous, nothing more, nothing less. It certainly has nothing to do with steady states. There are infinitely many functions that satisfy $\tilde{v}(0) = 1, \tilde{v}(\pi) = -1$ and you can use _any_ of them for $\tilde{v}$, we just chose the unique linear solution. For example, letting $\tilde{v} = -2 x^{2} / \pi^{2} + 1$ works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question.

Because your ODE in y is of second order, you can only obtain values of two constants out of three unknown constants A, B and $\alpha$ at a time. The third constant will be found later by using other boundary conditions imposed on your variable u in your PDE.

In case 2, you can evaluate A and B but $\alpha$ will still be arbitrary.

In case 3, you will find that $\sqrt{\lambda+4}$ should be an odd positive integer for your final equation to hold. Thus, $\sqrt{\lambda+4}=2n+1, n=0,1,2$ and so on. So, this time you found $\lambda$ and A but B will still be arbitrary.